# Rename folders with defective encoded german Umlauts

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have a folder with lots of subfolders with defective encoded german Umlauts.
Examples:

```
KÃ¶nige (K\xc3\x83\xc2\xb6nige) -> Könige
RealitÃ¤t (Realit\xc3\x83\xc2\xa4t) -> Realität
```

I wrote a python script, that reads all the folders and changes the defective encoded chars. I tried replace and translate but both does not work. Any ideas?
Here's what i got.

```
translation_dict = {
    u'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9': u'e',
    u'\xc3\x83\xc2\xbc': u'ü',
    u'\xc3\x83\xc2\x9f': u'ß',
    u'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa4': u'ä',
    u'\xc3\x83\xc2\xb6': u'ö',
    u'Ã¼': u'ü',
}

folders = read_folders(base_folder, ".*") # function returns list of folders

for folder in folders:
    changed = folder[1].translate(translation_dict)
```

But in the end, there are no changes.

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to print, view, or save your changes?

Comment: That's what happens if the file name is actually UTF-8 encoded, but you decode as e.g. ISO 8859-1, and then encode the result again as UTF-8. The solution is to use the correct encoding when you decode the file name the first time. I guess you can also revert that: First decode as UTF-8 again, then encode in ISO 8859-1 (or whatever was falsely used) and then decode again as UTF-8.

Comment: @user17732522 ocould you give a hint how that would look?

Comment: @a_cold The defect is inside `read_folders` which you are not showing or in whatever method you use to print the file names.

Comment: @user17732522 the read_folders method is just a wrapper for os.walk and a regex to filter certain folders.
The folders were saved wrong on my computer. I'm trying to bulk-fix them...

Comment: @a_cold `os.walk` gives you decoded strings. What exactly are these strings? You show some characters in your question, but also some encoding of them. How are you getting `KÃ¶nige` and `K\xc3\x83\xc2\xb6nige` from the result of `os.walk`? How exactly are you printing the strings? What does `repr` on the strings give you instead? The problem is that you need to reverse engineer exactly what incorrect sequence of encoding and decoding lead to the messy filenames and then you must invert that (although it is not possible to invert all such sequences).